# Are the names of lightroots the names of shrines spelled backwards?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Looking at your map in Tears of the Kingdom, you might notice that each lightroot is directly beneath a shrine. However, something I noticed when watching a video on Youtube is that the Nisoij lightroot is directly beneath the Jiosin shrine. While this isn't obvious, these names are the same, but spelled backwards. Does this relationship hold true for every shrine and lightroot pair?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [Lightroot](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Lightroot) wiki, your analysis is correct.

> The name of a Lightroot is the name of the above shrine, but backwards.

Comment: This fits well with the terrain of the Depths being the inverse of the above-ground terrain.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, every lightroot's name is the name of the corresponding surface shrine reversed.

Interestingly, however, the assertion that every lightroot is directly beneath a shrine is does *not* hold. I've encountered three lightroots (I don't recall which, though I could check again) that are not directly beneath their corresponding shrine, but rather about 10-100 meters offset.

Comment: No I don't think so. Every lightroot had a corresponding shrine on the surface. Note that this does not include those found in the sky. If you pay attention closer, you'll notice that the elevations in the depths seem to correspond to the elevations on the surface too, only inverted. i.e., High mountainous regions on the surface mean deep valleys in the depths. A literal "upside down."

Comment: @JeffMercado Every lightroot has a corresponding shrine on the surface, but not every one is *directly* below the corresponding shrine. The most notable one I've seen is that Turakawak Shrine (in the shallows of Lake Illumeni) is offset by fifty meters or so from being directly above Kawakarut Lightroot. Check for yourself; it's just between Gerudo Highlands and Tanagar Canyon, straight southwest of Tabantha Bridge Stable, on the west side of Hyrule.

Comment: @user23415 (who suggested an edit I rejected) I am not referring to sky shrines in what I said here. I am referring to shrines like Turakawak Shrine, which are on the surface but not directly above a lightroot. (The corresponding lightroot is about 50 meters southeast.)

Comment: I just unlocked them both today and you are 100% correct. The shrine on the surface is not directly above the lightroot. I wonder why, maybe because of the shrine puzzle forcing a relocation?

Comment: @fez The shrine is in the shallows, so perhaps it's just to be able to maintain the whole "surface water = depths walls" thing. Though a couple other shrines near water do violate that, so I dunno.