# Why do some minibosses share the same location in Hyrule/Depths and other don't?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

We already know that [each Lightroot is directly beneath a Shrine](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403309/are-the-names-of-lightroots-the-names-of-shrines-spelled-backwards), but I've noticed that something similar happens with many mini-bosses scattered around Hyrule and the Depths.

For example, under some Molduga's location there's a Frox, under several Stone Talus there's another Stone Talus, and at least one Hinox is directly below its counterpart from the overworld.

Are they related in any way? Is there a reason I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear to me whether the connection is direct or indirect.

Bosses tend to live in open arenas (for lack of a better word), and due to the relation of how Hyrule and the Depths relate to one another (inverted, but otherwise equal surface shape), wide open areas would naturally occur in the same spots on both maps.